# How to find if a text exists on page using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

If the text exists then click on `xyz` else click on `abc`.

I'm using the below `if` statement:

```
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]")).isDisplayed())
{    
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("logout")).getAttribute("href");          
} else {          
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/a[2]")).click();
}
```

Script fails with the following error message:

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]"}
```

Comment: Provide the HTML code please.

Answer (score 37):

**Try this code:**

The below code used to check the text presence in the entire web page.

```
if(driver.getPageSource().contains("your Text"))
{
    //Click xyz
}

else
{
    //Click abc
}
```

If you want to check the text on a particular web element

```
if(driver.findElement(By.id("Locator ID")).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Yor Text"))
{
    //Click xyz
}

else
{
    //Click abc
}
```

Comment: i experienced, that elements with display:none were returned as empty (no text), even when they contained text (chrome dev tools showed text)

Comment: is that first case sensitive or not?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, XPaths of this type and `byLinkText` are really bad locators and will fail frequently. The locators should be **descriptive, unique, and unlikely to change**. Priority is to use:

1. **ID**
2. **Class**
3. **CSS** ([better performence than XPath](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/34-xpath-vs-css-revisited-2))
4. **XPath**

Then you can use `getText()` on the element rather than on the entire page (`getPageSource()`) which is more specific. `try catch` is also a good practice for `isDisplayed()` as @Robbie stated, or better yet use [FluentWait](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12866/how-fluentwait-is-different-from-webdriverwait) to find the element:

```
// Waiting 10 seconds for an element to be present on the page, checking
// for its presence once every 1 second.
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
    .withTimeout(10, SECONDS)
    .pollingEvery(1, SECONDS)
    .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class)
    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
    .ignoring(ElementNotVisibleException.class)
```

Then use like so:

```
wait.until(x -> {
     WebElement webElement = driverServices.getDriver().findElement(By.id("someId"));
     return webElement.getText();
  });

wait.until(x -> {
     WebElement webElement = driverServices.getDriver().findElement(By.id("someOtherId"));
     return webElement.getAttribute("href");
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we can use try ,except function using python web driver. see below the code

```
webtable=driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath value")
print webtable.text
try:
   xyz=driver.find_element_by_xpath(("xpath value")
   xyz.click()

except:
   abc=driver.find_element_by_xpath(("xpath value")
   abc.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the "IsDisplayed" in a try catch.  "IsDisplayed" can only be called if the element exists.

You may want to override the Implicit Time Out as well, else the try/catch will take a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code:-

```
Assert.assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains(textOnThePage));
```