# Check if text on page Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am using Selenium IDE in FireFox.

I want to write an IF statement that will search through all text() on page, if it finds matching text echo "Found it", else echo "not found".

Where I have got so far:

```
*somehow search here hopefully Stackoverflow save the day*

store | FOUND IT | found
store | NOT FOUND | notfound

if | ${test}==true |
echo | ${found} |

else | |
echo | ${notfound} |

endIf | |
```

Please do **not** give me JavaScript code etc..., I am using the FireFox addon IDE.

Thank you!

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974508/webdriverhow-to-find-if-text-exists-on-page

Comment: @JosephEvans That doesn't use the `Selenium IDE`

Comment: Let's start of with saying that I don't have a clue how to write scripts for `Selnium IDE`. I do know that in the plugin there is an option `assertBodyText(pattern)`. This will check if the passed `pattern` is in the page source which seems to be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script.

```
storeText | css=body | text
storeEval |javascript{storedVars['text'].indexOf("Find me",0) > 0} | find
if | ${find}==true |
echo | FOUND IT|
else | |
echo | TEXT NOT FOUND |
endIf | |
```

In the sample, I stored all the text in the page body using the **text** variable then I used a javascript code to locate the *Find me* text in the variable. This is guaranteed working in Selenium IDE. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by Rodel is correct. But there is the way to make it in just one step.

```
echo | javascript{if (document.documentElement.innerHTML.indexOf('Text_to_find') > 0) {'Found'} else {'Not Found'}}
```